# How do I get a valid Microsoft Store Code Signing Certificate

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, code-signing, microsoft-store

I have an application published on Microsoft Store and I wanted to update it recently but when I submitted it resulted in an error:

Your submission does not have a valid code signing certificate.

> On June 16, 2022 we announced an update to Store policy. Win32 apps
> are required to be digitally signed, with a code signing certificate
> that chains up to a certificate issued by a Certificate Authority (CA)
> that is part of the Microsoft Trusted Root Program.
>
> New app submissions will not be allowed without an appropriate
> signature after May 1, 2023. Existing apps must be updated to include
> a digital signature per this policy before January 15, 2024.
>
> Previously, all Microsoft Store apps (native UWPs for example) were
> hosted and signed by the Microsoft Store and received a Microsoft
> signature. With the change to our policy enabling Win32 apps to be
> listed in the Microsoft Store, and the removal of the waitlist for
> submitting Win32s, the new policy requires those apps to be digitally
> signed, and ensures all apps that customers acquire and download from
> the Microsoft Store have a trusted digital certificate.

So I looked into it and all the answer I found was from 10 years ago. If anyone has any knowledge about this issue, How do I get a valid certificate? Where do I get a valid certificate? How do I sign my Win32 App and its .msi Installer? My application is made in WPF and The Installer is a "Setup Project" by an extension for Visual Studio by Microsoft.

Comment: You basically need to obtain an Authenticode code-signing certificate. You will need to purchase one from a Certificate Authority and they usually cost a few hundred dollars and require you to verify your identity (think providing passport ID etc.).

Comment: If you don't need specific features of the installer, alternatively you can make your app a packaged app using Windows Application Packaging Project.

Comment: The thing is, If I use Windows Application Packaging Project, I can't update my existing project because it is categorized as an exe/msi package and I am not sure I can change it.